# Having CSS Code Contradict Default CSS Code, Okay Or Not Okay?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this in my CSS:

```
div {
margin: 0;
overflow: auto;
padding: 1%;
text-align: center;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

That should be the default code for all div. But what if I have another div with a code that contradicts this default:

```
div.a {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid;
text-align: left;
}
```

As you can see, there's no contradiction with the background-color or border, but there is a contradiction in that this div is text-align: left whereas the default is text-align: center. I've actually used this code with html pages and have found no problems with browsers interpreting it. But I'm wondering if it's still bad practice or could lead to problems down the road.

Comment: Once you learn what the "C" in CSS means you will have answered your own question

Answer (score 1):

Contradiction isn't possible in style sheets - selectors are either more specific (and so override less specific selectors) or just come later and so override the previous selector's rules.

In your example the div.a selector is more specific as it selects by class and not just the tag name. This means it doesn't matter if your div.a rule comes before or after the div rules, the div.a rules will always apply because they are more specific.

The specificity rules may seem complex at first but you get used to them pretty quick.

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: This, which is exactly why this would be selected over the two div options:
`<div class="a" style="text-align:right;">blah</div>` unless of course the `!important` override is used somewhere.